# Different addresses of a pointer and an array in a union

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, unions

I want to get the address of the first element of an array. This array is in an union with a pointer.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union l_array_0_uint8_t {
  uint8_t *pnt;
  uint8_t array[8];

};

int main()
{
    union l_array_0_uint8_t u;
    uint8_t* aa = &(u.array[0]);
    uint8_t* pa = u.pnt;
    printf("array   inner: %p\n", aa);
    printf("Pointer inner: %p\n", pa);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
array   inner: 0x7ffdad959050
Pointer inner: 0x7ffdad959140
```

Why do this two addresses differ? I expected the array and the pointer to have the same address.

Comment: `uint8_t* pa = u.pnt;` does not set `pa` to the *address* of the member. It should be `uint8_t** pa = &u.pnt;`

Answer (score 3):

The result of expression `u.pnt` is not the address of the union member `u.pnt`. It is the value of the member. But the member has an indeterminate value, so your program has undefined behaviour.

To get the address, you can use the address-of operator (just like when you took the address of the other member):

```
uint8_t** pa = &u.pnt;
```